# Redis Cluster: Is it possible to obtain one hash slot from different keys?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

As I know from Redis cluster tutorial, cluster has only 16384 slots (0 - 16383). The hashslots are calculated by following command: `CRC16 (KEY) mod 16384`. So for example CRC16 of some key equals `16385` and hash slot will be `1`. For another key CRC16 equals `32769` and hash slot will be again `1`. Is it cause some conflict? Or first one will be rewritten by second one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand your question, no this is not a conflict. Each key belogns to one hashsolt but each hashslot can have many keys.

[image]

`CLUSTER GETKEYSINSLOT slot count`: https://redis.io/commands/cluster-keyslot